# Pandas Group data into decades

Tags: pandas

I have the following data and need to combine the years into their decades and then sum up the totals for each decade and add to a bar chart. Can you help me out on this, please?

Here is my data:

```
    year   value
    1971    9823.5
    1971    5661.4
    1972    3250.4
    1972    2959.1
    1973    2510.8
    1973    2071.6
    1973    2056.1
    1974    1705.3
    1974    1703.6
    1975    1687.7
    1975    1667.4
    1975    1660.3
    1976    1631
    1976    1574.4
    1977    1526.2
    1977    1312.1
    1977    1210.3
    1978    1113.3
    1978    1090.1
    1979    1033.2
    1979    1021.5
    1979    994.1
    1980    941
    1980    923.7
    1981    916
    1981    915.2
    1981    911
    1982    846.3
    1982    813.2
    1983    794.6
    1983    783
    1983    782.6
    1984    776.8
    1984    732.9
    1985    708.3
    1985    681.2
    1985    680.5
    1986    659.5
    1986    654.2
    1987    652.4
    1987    648.6
    1987    645.8
    1988    633.5
    1988    630.7
    1989    616.2
    1989    607.7
    1989    596.2
    1990    533.1
    1990    532
    1991    530.8
    1991    519.7
    1991    509.5
    1992    500.1
    1992    492.9
    1993    492.9
    1993    487.6
    1993    484.1
    1994    475.1
    1994    470.1
    1995    466.8
    1995    461.4
    1995    461.1
    1996    459
    1996    454.8
    1997    440.9
    1997    440.9
    1997    438.3
    1998    431
    1998    428.3
    1999    428.2
    1999    423.6
    1999    419.3
    2000    415.9
    2000    413.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `(df.year//10)*10` (HERE 2000 is not included in 1990-2000):

```
k2 = df.groupby((df.year//10)*10)['value'].sum().reset_index()
sns.barplot(x=k2['year'], y=k2['value'])
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

OR use `pd.cut` (HERE 2000 is include in 1990-2000):

```
import seaborn as sns

k = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.year, bins=range(df.year.min() - 1,
                                          df.year.max()+1, 10)))['value'].sum().reset_index()
fig = sns.barplot(x=k['year'], y=k['value'])
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Wow, amazing,  thanks for your help , much appreciated